# Application of Exponential Shift Theorem in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently doing MIT's OCW for Differential Equations and have run into a bit of trouble with respect to applying the Exponential Shift Theorem in order to get the particular solution of an ODE. The problem is:
$$y^{(4)} - 2y^{(2)} + y = xe^x$$

The linear operator involved can be described as:
$$p(D) = D^4 - 2D^2 + 1$$
$$p(D) = (D^2 - 1)^2$$
From here I concluded that 1 is a 2nd order root of the characteristic equation. From this I guessed the particular solution form:
$$y_p(x) = x^2e^x(Ax+B)$$
With the constant of the exponential being incorporated into $Ax+B$. Now in order to get Ax+B I want to apply the Differential Operator onto the guessed solution: 
$$p(D)[x^2e^x(Ax+B)]=xe^x$$
$$(D^2-1)^2[e^xx^2(Ax+B)]$$
Using Exponential Shift Theorem (as I understand it) 
$$e^x(D^2)^2x^2(Ax+B) = xe^x$$
$$e^xD^4x^2(Ax+B) = xe^x$$
$$e^xD^4(Ax^3+Bx^2) = xe^x$$
And there's the problem. I can't solve for A or B from this since it ends up being $x = 1$ which doesn't make sense. Is there something I'm missing here? Am I applying the Exponential Shift Theorem wrongly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have instead
$$
e^xp(D+1)[Ax^3+Bx^2]=e^x((D+1)^2-1)^2[Ax^3+Bx^2]=xe^x.
$$